# How do I correctly switch from an A record to a CNAME?

Tags: dns, cname, a-records, hubspot

I have these settings in my zone file and I want to add a CNAME for my web traffic to use instead. Do I delete these A records, or do I edit them to work with my new CNAME below? (xxx.xxx.xx.xx is my old server IP which I will no longer be using)

**www                     A       xxx.xxx.xx.xx**

**mydomain.com.           A       xxx.xxx.xx.xx**

and I need to add a CNAME like this

**www CNAME 123456.group32.sites.hubspot.net**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you will have to delete your A records first.

Please keep in mind you can not (not advisable) have a CNAME for the "naked" domain (e.g. yourdomain without subdomain).

Comment: Thank you!

I don't understand what you mean by yourdomain without subdomain. I'm setting this up to take my Hubspot website live. They only gave me this one CNAME to add to my settings. Are you saying there should be a second CNAME?

Comment: Lets say your domain is example.com.
the "naked" domain would be simply "example.com". But you also want people to reach your website over the subdomain "www" - e.g. www.example.com.

Hubspot needs to supply IP addresses which you can use as A-Entry for your naked domain. For all your subdomains you can use the CNAME.